# Cross-OS Vanilla Python Mouse Get/Set

Tags: python, cross-platform, mouse

Using Python 2.7.10 and above, is there any way to retrieve and set the absolute mouse position with only the pre-installed libraries (no pygame, PyUserInput, Xlib, PyQt, pyautogui, PyMouse, etc.)?

- This needs to work in all OSes as well (Linux, Mac, Windows).
- The solution must work in the newest version of Python, as well as 2.7.10
- I also can't have the user interact within a popup window, since it isn't relative, and the user still needs to be able to interact with other windows.
- Also, if possible is there a way to cancel the default action triggered by the mouse event (like `e.preventDefault()` in JavaScript)?

Additional kudos if keyboard event interceptions/simulation is also possible with the same requirements.

Comment: You can write an answer, or at least please elaborate. Why not just use the same method as one of the Python libs?

Comment: What method? What lib?

Comment: Any of the libs that I mentioned in the post, such as pygame, PyMouse,  or Xlib (which is also Unix-specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure assuming you can do it in an OS-Specific way first for each operating system

```
def getMouseCoords():
    if "Windows" in platform.uname():
       return get_windows_mouse()
    elif os.path.exists("/dev/input/mouse"):
       return parse_filesys_mouse()
    elif some_otheros_condition:
       return get_some_other_os_mouse()
```

you would of coarse have to figure out an os-specific way to accomplish the task for each os you want to cross support ...

setting them may be more complicated ...

vetoing the events will likely be very very hard

**there is not universal way of doing input events as each OS implements it differently**

of coarse this is a non-trivial task, luckily people have built libraries such as **PyMouse** that do this for you .... I suppose you could just copy and paste all their code, but how is that any different than just using the library as intended?

Comment: Great answer, I was afraid that implementing OS-specific solutions separately was the only solution. But I still want to see if there are any better solutions out there. Also, I can't ask clients to install libraries when running the program. I want to make the Python script as easy to use as possible. Would the libraries be written in Python or some other language?

Comment: you dont ... you bundle it into your package that you are providing ... (much like c/c++ programs often bundle in additional libraries ...) ,  pymouse actually uses other libraries depending on the OS that is being targeted (ie in windows it uses win32api, which is a wrapper around the win32 dll's that MS supplies, in linux it uses X11 wrappers, I no idea how macs work however)... really to start with you should target just one OS ...

Comment: I would really prefer to only provide one single `.py` file. This is meant to be used by clients in a development environment. Keeping the file as small as possible is a definite plus, so if anyone else has more elegant solutions, I would like to see them. Sorry!

Comment: no problems there ... but I really doubt you will find a solution ... why dont you just make a pypy package that developers can just `pip install` then? most developers download a zip and run something like `python setup.py install` that installs and verifies your dependencies

Comment: it seems to me like you are perhaps putting the cart before the horse ... why not start by targeting a single OS and using packages as you need them ... then you can freeze your developement into an installable module ... I think you are missing a few key links in your workflow and worrying about this at this juncture is largely pointless and is going to cause you to have alot of issues that you dont need to deal with